# Conditionally updating a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a dataframe of `1/0` or `True/False` based on two different thresholds. I currently have a dataframe like this:

```
          col1    col2    col3    col4...
    time
       0  0.42    0.01    0.02    0.33
       1  0.51    0.02    0.01    0.45
       2  0.35    0.00    0.48    0.67
```

And I want to create a new dataframe based on the 'on' threshold of `value > 0.4` and 'off' threshold of `value < 0.3`:

```
          col1    col2    col3    col4...
    time
       0     1       0       0       0
       1     1       0       0       1
       2     1       0       1       1
```

So even though `(time=2,col1)` is smaller than 0.4, it still takes the value 1 because the value before it is 1 and the value is greater than 0.3.

Comment: So why does time 0 and col 1 equals on when the value is 0.4 and not > 0.4?

Comment: Because I have the additional 'off' threshold of value < 0.3. So `if value in row-1 == 1 && value < 0.3 then value = 0` but `if value in row-1 == 0 && value < 0.4 then value = 0`. Intended to be a kind of control to stop the value changing between 1 and 0 every row unless there is a (relatively) large jump.

Comment: So if time 0/col1 had value 0.31 it would be considered on? Why is time 0 col4 not on then? It's unclear if you mean `>` or `>=`

Comment: So are you looking for `np.logical_or((df > 0.4),(df.shift() >= 0.3)).astype(int)`?

Comment: So `on_threshold=0.4` and `off_threshold=0.3`. To become `1` the `value` must be `>on_threshold`, once a column is at `1` the `value` must satisfy `<off_threshold` to return to `0`.

Comment: @EdChum, I'll probably use your solution of `((grouped > on_threshold) | ((grouped.shift() > on_threshold)) & (grouped > off_threshold))).astype(int)` since I believe it is sufficient for my use actually, if you want to re submit it I'll accept it :)

Comment: It doesn't really deal with all conditions, just with your specific dataset though which is why I deleted it as technically it is incorrect. I also don't like solutions that use pandas dfs where it ultimately becomes a for loop which I think is the only way to handle all situations correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
threshold_func_last = 0
def reset_threshold_func():
    global threshold_func_last
    threshold_func_last = 0

def threshold_func(value):
    global threshold_func_last
    if value > 0.4:
        threshold_func_last = 1
    elif value < 0.3:
        threshold_func_last = 0
    return threshold_func_last

df_out = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df.columns:
    reset_threshold_func()
    df_out[column] = df[column].apply(threshold_func)
```

Comment: This is nearly what I need, except now the first value in `col4` shows up as 1 because it is greater than `0.3` and the last value of `col3` is greater than 0.4. Is there a way to reset the global var once the end of the column has been reached before moving on to the next column?

Comment: Just needed to reset the global between columns. I've updated the code in my answer.